# Confusion with NSDate and timezones

Tags: ios, nsdate

My problem is that I am converting a timestamp to a string and back to a `NSDate` at runtime. The string is specified to be in GMT:0, but I live in GMT:-9 . Every time I try to work with a date converted from a string and detect the interval between a current `NSDate` and the `NSDate` from string I get a wrong `NSTimeInterval` value.

Here are my functions:

```
+(NSString*) timeStampString{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[BBuyoUtilities timeStamp]];

}

+(NSDate*) timeStampToDate:(NSString*) timeStamp{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
    //This didnt work
    //[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    //Works with
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    NSDate* returnDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStamp];
    return returnDate;
}
```

Comment: Note: `NSDate` saves the date relative to GMT no matter what timezone it is created in. So use the local timezone and calculate tie intervals use `timeIntervalSinceDate:`.

Comment: Also note that in each of the functions you're specifying different time zones - one set to GMT/UTC, the other set to whatever the timezone on your device is - so you're comparing apples to oranges. Internally everything is held in UTC, but you have to be careful at the interface where you import/export the user string representation.

Comment: do you say I should replace the systemTimeZone call with timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT? Do I need that at all?

Comment: In you're second sequence you're using the "system" (ie, local) timezone.  And you negate the timezone present in the string by specifying a literal "Z" to match the "Z" presumably in the string.  So it will assume that the timestamp you're reading is local timezone.  If you want the "Z" in the string to be treated as a timezone you need to specify a non-literal "Z" in the format string.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help so far. I was assuming that my Z specification was not correct. What should I use for Z then? Also, if I change systemTimeZone back to timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0 it should be consistent?

Comment: There is a big difference between a pattern of `"'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"` and `"'HH':'mm':'ssZ"`.  In the former the `Z` is a literal, meaning that it's supposed to match up with `Z` in the time string (just like the `:`).  Otherwise the `Z` has no meaning.  In the latter the `Z` indicates that the time string should be parsed for a timezone field in the ["ISO8601 basic format"](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  (And "Z" in that format means "Zulu" or GMT timezone.)

Comment: If you get the time zone spec right in your format string then it won't matter what timezone you set for the formatter.